# How do I make this piece of code clean and fast

Tags: python, code-cleanup

I have about 20 lists that I'm appending to in each iteration of a loop if some checks are passed. The appended values come from a nested dictionary and as you can imagine, writing these one by one looks super ugly and reduces readability. My code looks something like this:

```
list1.append(my_dict['key1']['key2']['key3'])
list2.append(my_dict['key1']['key2']['key4']['key5'])
.
.
.
list19.append(my_dict['key1']['key2']['key4']['key19'])
list20.append(my_dict['key1']['key2']['key4']['key20'])
```

I'd like to just take all those append operations and put it into a function, but the idea of giving a bunch of lists into a function, appending to them and returning them seems wrong to me. I'm not sure what the most Pythonic way to do this is.

EDIT: I'm adding this dict below to give you guys an idea of what I'm extracting into the lists

```
"impact" : {
  "baseMetricV2" : {
    "cvssV2" : {
      "version" : "2.0",
      "vectorString" : "AV:N/AC:L/Au:N/C:N/I:N/A:P",
      "accessVector" : "NETWORK",
      "accessComplexity" : "LOW",
      "authentication" : "NONE",
      "confidentialityImpact" : "NONE",
      "integrityImpact" : "NONE",
      "availabilityImpact" : "PARTIAL",
      "baseScore" : 5.0
    },
    "severity" : "MEDIUM",
    "exploitabilityScore" : 10.0,
    "impactScore" : 2.9,
    "obtainAllPrivilege" : false,
    "obtainUserPrivilege" : false,
    "obtainOtherPrivilege" : false,
    "userInteractionRequired" : false
  }
```

Note here, that the key impact refers to key1. But the question I'm asking doesn't specifically have anything to do with the data I'm extracting. I just feel like giving a bunch of lists to a function, modifying those lists inside the function, returning and overwriting the original lists at the output is wrong. It's more of a coding philosophy question that I'll be applying over many cases, rather than it being used solely in this specific case.

Comment: 1. You need to explain the rule for getting only 3 keys in first row and 4 keys on next rows. 2. Maybe https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is more suitable place for this question.

Comment: There is no rule it's just me randomly picking out some values from arbitrarily deep dictionaries into a bunch of lists.

Comment: Can you add some inputs and the expected output?

Comment: if your repeating yourself alot there is probably a better way to do it. showing sample input / data and expected output / data will make it easier for people to give suggestions.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to stackoverflow. Please have a look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example